# Запуск VBS из Bat-файла

Tags: bat, vbscript

Имею рабочий Bat-файл и рабочий VBS. По отдельности отрабатывают без ошибок. Но при запуске VBS из Bat-файла, пишет: "Разрешение отклонено".

Запускал так:

1. `start /w wscript.exe %VBScriptPath%`
2. `cscript %VBScriptPath%`

VBS и Bat лежат в одной папке.

Посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Строка из VBS, на которую указывает ошибка при вызове:

```
Set File = FileObject.CreateTextFile("test.txt", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня работают все три способа

> 1) start /w wscript.exe %VBScriptPath%
>
> 2) cscript %VBScriptPath%
>
> 3) %VBScriptPath%

Может у Вас `%VBScriptPath%` содержит пробелы и нужно его обрамить кавычками?

Comment: Кавычки не помогли. В ошибке дополнительно указано строка 5, символ 1. МОжет в самом скрипте дело, но почему тогда он работает отдельно. Дополню вопрос этой строкой.

Answer (score 0):

Короче дело и правда было в скрипте. Оказывается в моём случае нужно обязательно указывать фактический(полный) путь к test.txt.

Comment: Посмотрите переменные при `WScript`. Я выходил из ситуации так `var csv = fs.CreateTextFile(WScript.ScriptName.toLowerCase().replace(".js",".csv"),1);`

Comment: и ещё есть хорошая штука - дебаггер `start /w wscript.exe //x %VBScriptPath%` параметр **//х**